# How to connect power phototriac's gate pin?

Tags: opto-isolator, triac

I have inherited a design that uses a power phototriac (basically an optotriac with a built-in TRIAC) -- the [VO2223B](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83312/vo2223b.pdf) -- that includes a pin to access the power TRIAC's gate (pin 5 below).

[image: VO2223B pinout]

The datasheet gives no hints on what to do with this pin, and neither do any app notes from Vishay that I have found.  Should I keep this pin floating as in its current design, or should it be tied to one of the anodes through some passives?

Comment: I think you leave it floating.   Current has to flow through the triac's gate, and if it is floating there's no place for it to flow.  I'm not expert at triacs and scrs, so I'm not going to make an answer out of this guess.

Comment: @JRE Right -- I thought perhaps it's broken out for noise-suppression potential or what have you.  Or some sort of dv/dt or di/dt limiting to reduce the need of a snubber (that'd be wonderful!).

Answer (score 1):

That is a bias pin.  It allows you to make it harder or easier to trigger the triac.

Comment: Okay, I buy that.  Can you elaborate or provide some references?

Comment: Fair answer. I was thinking bias as well but I couldn't find any information on how it would affect any characteristics of the circuit. I would definitely upvote your answer if you're able to provide this :)

Comment: Agree that a gate resistor will make it less sensitive. Since the vendor didn't mention it, this implies that they don't expect you to use it. But, they really should explicitly say this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but my best guess is that they left it on two pins to connect a snubber. The picture below uses two triacs, the same circuit could be build from the V02223B

[image]
Source: https://www.vishay.com/docs/84963/phototriacsfaqs.pdf

Comment: Ah, but the next question (13. Q: WHEN IS IT REQUIRED TO USE A PHOTOTRIAC AS POWER TRIAC DRIVER?) is the one that actually references Fig. 5.